# arrow body style issue

Tags: javascript, react-native

New to react, and just running some test programs but I already ran into and error with he following code. already tried adding parenthesis in various places and removing the return statement as recommended in other post. I'm sure there is something simple I am overlooking. Please help, Thank you.

Exact Error Msg:
"Unexpected block statement surrounding arrow body. (arrow-body-style)"

```
const Header = () => { 
   return <Text> Albums! </Text>;
};
```

Comment: have you tried `const Header = () => <Text> Albums! </Text>;`

Answer (score 1):

The return statement is unnecessary.

```
const Header = () => (
  <Text> Albums! </Text>
);
```

Comment: So are the parentheses around the return value